# bash scripts not running

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm seeing a weird problem that just started after a reboot. I tried rebooting again. My scripts aren't running.  This is a script called test.  I did `chmod +x test` of course.

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "hello world"
```

It doesn't produce any output.  The echo works fine as a command-line.  I've also tried ...

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "hello world" >> y
```

And y isn't created.  Again it works as a command-line. My version is ...

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Any ideas?

Edit: Scripts are running from crontab.  So it is a shell problem. I've tried executing bash first but it doesn't help.

EDIT2: `bash test` works!  What does this mean?  I've never had to do this before.  `$SHELL` is `/bin/bash`.  This is still a problem for me.

Comment: Remove the space in your shebang

Comment: Do you mean "my scripts are running" **automatically**? Are they in a crontab entry or someother automated system? The space looks like a problem. Let us know. Good luck

Comment: @DanielA.White for me the code works with space in the shebang. Is this version dependent?

Comment: It sounds like you expect them to run automatically.  Where are you triggering them?

Comment: Add the cronjob to your question (no comment).

Comment: I'm just running them from the command-line.  Scripts in crontab work.  I've tried the first line with and without the space.  I also tried it without the first line, which has always worked for me.  All my scripts don't have that first line.

Comment: My crontab is just a bunch or random scripts which are all working.

Comment: If your script is called `test`, that's already a bad idea. And why did you `chmod +x test-script` if your script isn't called `test-script`?

Comment: *"works with space in the shebang. Is this version dependent?"* ... No, not version dependent. "shebang" lines are a super-old feature of unix executable processing where the OS looks at the first line to find the path to the program that should execute the curent file. This is part of the `file` and `magic` file system. .... What do you get for `echo "SHELL=$SHELL  and    BASH_VERSION=$BASH_VERSION"`? Good luck.

Comment: `cat -vet test-script`. Do you see `^M$` at the end of each line? yes? `dos2unix test-script`. Turn off DOS/WIndows line endings in your code editor. Also https://shellcheck.net , copy/paste with the `#!/bin/bash` as first line. Fix any errors flagged. Finally, read  the items on this page : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Skip the Version information at the top and search for the sections  labeled "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question" .Good luck.

Comment: @DanielA.White and @runr, it's always OK to have a space after the `#!` on the shebang line.  See [Is space allowed between #! and /bin/bash in shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276751/264812).

Comment: Actual name of the script file is test, not test-script.  It was a typo.  "echo $SHELL" gives "/bin/bash".  "echo $BASH_VERSION" gives "4.4.20(1)-release".  "cat -vet test" shows just $ at end of lines.  Is ^m visible?  Lines end with only \n because I typed it in with nano.

Comment: `bash test` should not work and print something like `bash test
/usr/bin/test: /usr/bin/test: cannot execute binary file` *unless you have removed files or messed with PATH*

Comment: It's not a good idea to call a program `test` because [test](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-test) is a shell builtin, and a `test` program is also usually available at `/usr/bin/test`.

Comment: I assume you were just using `test` to execute your script. `./test` should have worked fine, both because is avoids invoking the shell built-in or the standard command in your `PATH`, and because the shell isn't looking in your current directory for a command named `test`. (Or at least, you *shouldn't* have `.` on your `PATH` for security reasons.)

Answer (score 2):

As several people suggested my problem was a name conflict with the built in test.

Comment: Yep, in shell `[..]` is synonymous with `test`. (renaming builtins is bad juju...)